# Задержка при переборе каждого блока

Tags: jquery

На странице есть несколько блоков, я прохожусь по каждому с помощью кода:

```
 $('#wrap .block').each(function() {
      ....
 }
```

Внутри этого перебора я делаю клик по ссылке ( `trigger('click')` ) и мне нужно чтобы переход к разбору следующего блока началось спустя **3** секунд после текущего.

То есть что-то вроде:

```
 $('#wrap .block').each(function() {
      .....trigger('click');
      -- ждем 3 секунды ---
      -- делаем что нужно ---
      -- и переходим к следующему блоку --
 }
```

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 3):

Функция внутри each получает номер текущего элемента в качестве аргумента. Можно использовать его, чтобы поставить таймаут, кратный индексу... * 3000 миллисекунд.

```js
$('#wrap .block').each(function(index) {
  var t = $(this);
  setTimeout(function(){
    // Ваш код
    t.text( index ).css('background-color', '#999');
  }, 3000 * index);
});
```

```css
#wrap { display: flex; }

.block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrap">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Можно было выполнить то же самое без each, через `setInterval`... но он тикает бесконечно, если его не остановить. Придется немного заморочиться)

```js
var $block = $('#wrap .block');
var index = 0;

var interval = setInterval(function(){
  if( index == $block.length ) clearInterval( interval );
  
  // Основной код.
  // Текущий блок: $block.eq(index)
  
  $block.eq(index).text( index ).css('background-color', '#999');
  
  index++ // В конце каждого вызова, индекс увелчивается на 1.
}, 3000);
```

```css
#wrap { display: flex; }

.block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrap">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Обращаю внимание, что два варианта выше срабатывают раз в 3 секунды, а не ровно через 3 секунды после обработки предыдущего элемента. Если там какой-то лютый длинно-выполняемый код, будет правильнее вызывать следуюущую только после выполнения предыдущей. Для этого можно создать функцию, которая в конце выполнения будет вызывать саму себя через 3 секунды:

```js
var $block = $('#wrap .block');
var i = 0;

recursiveTimeout();

function recursiveTimeout(){
  if( i == 5 ) { return; }
  
  $block.eq(i).text( i ).css('background-color', '#999');  
  // Здесь может произойти всё что угодно.
  // Следующий круг не начнется, пока этот не закончится.

  i++;
  setTimeout( recursiveTimeout, 3000 );
}
```

```css
#wrap { display: flex; }

.block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrap">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

P.s. Как сделать только на чистом js (с) Leks

```js
let block = document.querySelectorAll('#wrap .block');

for( let i = 0; i < block.length; i++ ){
  setTimeout(function(){
    block[i].style.backgroundColor = '#999';
    block[i].textContent = i;
  }, 1500 * i);
}
```

```css
#wrap { display: flex; }

.block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: как сделать только на чистом js ?

Comment: @Leks А там всё то же самое, только слова немного другие)) Добавил.

Comment: спасибо юольшое

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME [магическое число в профиле](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5P3r.png) Плюс конечно за ответ :)